# When attempting to fit data to an exponential curve in python, I get a strange set of errors

Tags: python, curve-fitting

I have a set of data in a 15x55 matrix in a separate file which I import and pull data from using this code:

```
ScanNum = []

#Import the data
data = loadtxt('FNScan40.txt')

#Define columns
ccd1= data[:,14]
t= data[:,0]
```

I am confident about this part of the code because I have used it in other code and had that work. I then defined the function to which I wanted to fit the data.

```
def Kinetics(tk,A,B):
f=A*(1.0-math.e**(-B*tk))
return f
```

Where A and B are the unknown coefficients.
Then, I put the x and y data that I have into arrays.

```
x = array([t])
y = array([ccd1])
```

Up until here I am pretty sure that everything is correct, it is when I actually try to perform the curve fit that I have trouble. This is the rest of the code that I have:

```
popt, pcov = curve_fit(Kinetics, x, y, p0=None)

print popt, pcov

plt.figure()
plt.plot(x, kinetics(x, *popt), label="Fitted Curve")
plt.show()
```

When I execute the code I get the error message: Improper input: N=2 must not exceed M=1. I know that N is the number of data points while M is the number of initial parameters. I am not sure how to fix this. The only thing I found to try was to set my own initial parameters, so in the above code I defined p0=[1,1] (since I have two parameters I am trying to guess, A and B.) This only resulted in the same error(Improper input: N=2 must not exceed M=1), so I tried varying how many '1's I put in. If I go over two I just get an error saying I've tried to enter too many arguments into Kinetics, which makes sense.

I've tried everything I could think of/ find on the Internet to no avail. If M is the initial parameters, why doesn't changing the number of '1's in p0 change what the error reports as M? What can I do to fix this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem I was encountering was in the arrays. I decided to look at the actual arrays to see if they were the issue. When I included brackets around 't' and 'ccd1', it set the length of the array equal to one. Taking out the brackets fixed that problem. There are other, unrelated issues in the code that should be pretty easily resolved.